# Javascript confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, onclick, confirmation

I am new to javascript and web development, now I am experimenting in codeigniter and I want to setup a javascript confirmation box on a delete link. Now I got it to work reasonably well using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function con(message) {
        var answer = confirm(message);
        if (answer)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and this:

```
echo '<a href="/groups/deletegroup/'.$group->id.'" OnClick="return con(\'Are you sure you want to delete the group?\');" class="btn small light-grey block">Delete</a>';
```

The problem I have is that the first time one clicks the link there is no popup, but every click after that works as it should. I also feel that maybe I should use document.getElementById and window.onload to get it to work properly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I eventually used a jquery solution looking like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('.delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.msgAlert({
        title: 'Delete'
        ,text: 'Do you really want to delete this group?'
        ,type: 'error'
        ,callback: function () {
                location.href = href;
        }
    });
})
```

});

I use the commercial msgUI for the msgAlert box.

Comment: is the script tag above or after the link declaration in your code?

Comment: it's above at the top of the page

Comment: try direct `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the group?')"`

Comment: Thank you! The direct one worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="btn-delete">Delete</a>
```

**JS:**

```
//window.onload = function() {
    var btnDelete = document.getElementById('btn-delete');
    btnDelete.onclick = function() {
        var message = 'Are you sure you want to delete the group?';
        if (confirm(message)) {
            // delete something...
        }
    }
//};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PEHx9/

Comment: I am trying this, but it does not popup anything, and my javascript console spits this out:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: What browser/version do you have?

Comment: Link-only answers are not future proof, please include the relevant code in your answer.